# Parse alamofire response into JSON return nil

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to parse data from alamofire response. If i print all response it works good, but if i want to print specific parametr form JSON, for example "firstName" it is returning nil.

```
    AF.request("http://localhost:5000/api/users").responseJSON(completionHandler: { (res) in
        
        switch res.result {
        case let .success(value):

            let xjson : JSON = JSON(res.value)
            print(xjson["firstName"].string)

        case let .failure(error):
            print(error)
        }
    })
```

No errors in console

Code below

```
    AF.request("http://localhost:5000/api/users").responseJSON(completionHandler: { (res) in
        
        switch res.result {
        case let .success(value):

            let xjson : JSON = JSON(res.value)
            print(xjson)
            print(xjson["firstName"].string)
        case let .failure(error):
            print(error)
        }
        
    })
```

returns

```
[
  {
    "dateOfBirth" : "1998-11-18T00:00:00.000Z",
    "_id" : "5f6a29ed16444afd36e9fe15",
    "email" : "sdasd@mail.com",
    "__v" : 0,
    "firstName" : "adam",
    "lastName" : "kowalski",
    "accountCreateDate" : "2020-09-22T16:44:29.692Z",
    "userPassword" : "12345",
    "userLogin" : "loginakowalski"
  }
]
nil
```

Comment: can you also post full json string, that prints when you print entire response?

Comment: try with only value in JSON as parameter instead of res.value

Comment: Added response from console

Comment: Your JSON is an Array at top level, not a Dictionary. That's why it fails.

Comment: you have an array `[]` of objects in the json, not the json object directly `{}`.. so what you need is `firstName`, from `first` object in the json array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `xjson` is an `Array` of `JSON`(looks User) objects. So you need to access the array elements as below,

```
let xjson : JSON = JSON(res.value)
if let firstUser = xjson.array?.first {
    print(firstUser["firstName"] as? String)
}
```

You can also put your `JSON` response [here](https://app.quicktype.io?share=SipGEIDoh5zQ0iw02DFH) and get the required data types and decoding code for free.

Comment: Your code return error: Value of type '(String, JSON)' has no subscripts

Comment: Just replace `xjson.first` with `xjson.array?.first`.

Comment: I replaced and now no error but it still return nil...

Comment: I also have a warning "Cast from 'JSON' to unrelated type 'String' always fails"

Comment: @Kamran also replace `firstUser["firstName"] as? String` with `firstUser["firstName"].stringValue`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone for your help. Below is the code that returns the correct value:

```
    AF.request("http://localhost:5000/api/users").responseJSON(completionHandler: { (res) in
        
        switch res.result {
        case let .success(value):

            let xjson : JSON = JSON(res.value)
            if let firstUser = xjson.array?.first {
                print(firstUser["firstName"].string!)
            }
        
        case let .failure(error):
            print(error)
        }
    })
```